# How to create a Dynamic Office 365 Group

Tags: azure, powershell, exchange-server

I am new to Exchange Online, and Azure, but Ive been asked if we can create O365 groups in Exchange Online, using the New-UnifiedGroup and Set-UnifiedGroup cmdlets.  Then they want to be able to make those groups dynamic, based upon certain criteria.  Is this even possible, or do I skip Exchange Online entirely, and in Azure use the New-AzureADMSGroup cmdlets to create a dynamic group.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Any update on your side? Is this helpful?

Comment: Yes I believe I have finally figured this out.  You need to use both Exchange Online,(New-UnifiedGroup/Set-UnifiedGroup) cmdlets and also make a connection to AzureAD and use the Set-AzureADMSGroup cmdlet.  I will post code later today, just fine tuning it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create an Office 365 group with AzureAD PowerShell cmdlet [New-AzureADMSGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsgroup?view=azureadps-2.0) and you need to install [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) module first.

For example, This command creates a new dynamic group with the following rule:

> user.department -contains "Marketing"
>
> The double quotation marks are replaced with single quotation marks.
>
> The processing state is On. This means that all users in the directory
>   that qualify the rule are added as members to the group. Any users
>   that do not qualify are removed from the group.

```
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "Dynamic Group 01" -Description "Dynamic group created from PS" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule "(user.department -contains ""Marketing"")" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

More references: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/New-enhancements-to-the-AzureAD-PowerShell-2-0-preview-Manage/ba-p/245153

and https://blog.hubfly.com/office-365/useful-powershell-cmdlets-to-administer-office-365-groups-part-1

Comment: This creates an AzureAD security Group that is Dynamic.  What I want is an Office365 Group that is Dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the solution we came up with.

## Requires AzureADPreview module, current version as of today 2.0.2.17

The AzureAD Module wont work, as it is missing parameters required for group membership.

## Requires a Connection into AzureAD, and also Exchange Online.

The account you connect with need to be an Exchange Administrator in Exchange Online, and an User Administrator in AzureAD.
In our example we want an Office group, that is dynamic, and the membershipRule based upon extensionattribute12.

```
#***********************************************************************
$ADUser = "samAccountName@yourdomain"
$ADPassword = 'the password'
$ADPwd = $ADPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = new-object system.management.automation.pscredential $ADuser, $ADPwd
#***********************************************************************
"Connect AzureAD"
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $UserCredential

"Connect to Exchange Online"
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

#######################################
function ConvertStaticGroupToDynamic
{
     Param([string]$groupId, [string]$dynamicMembershipRule)
     $dynamicGroupTypeString = "DynamicMembership"
     #existing group types
     [System.Collections.ArrayList]$groupTypes = (Get-AzureAdMsGroup -Id $groupId).GroupTypes

     if($groupTypes -ne $null -and $groupTypes.Contains($dynamicGroupTypeString))
     {
         throw "This group is already a dynamic group. Aborting conversion.";
     }
     #add the dynamic group type to existing types
     $groupTypes.Add($dynamicGroupTypeString)

     #modify the group properties to make it a static group: i) change GroupTypes to add the dynamic type, ii) start execution of the rule, iii) set the rule
     Set-AzureAdMsGroup -Id $groupId -GroupTypes $groupTypes.ToArray() -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On" -MembershipRule $dynamicMembershipRule
}
#######################################
$ExtAtt12 = "Marketing"
$NewGroupName = "O365-OfficeGroupTest"
"[$NewGroupName] create group"
New-UnifiedGroup -DisplayName $NewGroupName
Set-UnifiedGroup $NewGroupName -UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled:$false
$ID = (Get-UnifiedGroup $NewGroupName).ExternalDirectoryObjectId
sleep 15 # Allow time for Exchange Online to Sync with AzureAD
ConvertStaticGroupToDynamic -groupId $ID -dynamicMembershipRule "(User.extensionattribute12 -eq ""$ExtAtt12"")"
```